# How to combinie multiple annotations in one and rename their attributes

Tags: java, annotations

The intention is to group together several spring validation annotations, and rebadge their default attributes. A simpflied example, given:

```
class @interface A {
    int value();
}
class @interface B {
    int value();
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
class @interface Combo {
    int a(); // have this directed to A.value
    int b(); // have this directed to B.value
}
```

So in usage it would look like:

```
@Combo(a = 1, b = 2)
```

And have the effect of

```
@A(1)
@B(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand , **Java does not support merging annotations** as the compiler does not provide the functionality.
It's fairly easy to combine annotations in **spring**. For instance :

```
class @interface A {
    int value();
}
class @interface B {
    int value();
}

@A
@B
class @interface Combo {
    int a(); // have this directed to A.value
    int b(); // have this directed to B.value
}
```

The above code would work on spring and that is how many of the spring-boot annotations are created . For instance , `@SpringBootApplication` is a combination of three annotations mainly : `@ComponentScan, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @SpringBootConfiguration`.

Comment: @Bohemian I corrected my wording, sorry It won't work in java as Java doesn't support the capability. I think framework like spring , use reflections to provide this functionality which is absent in plain java.